# C++ assignment operator associativity

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

after the following  c++ code, the array a contains: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

```
int a[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};
int i = 2;
a[i++] = a[i++];
```

i expected it to be: 0, 1, 3, 3, 4

could anyone explain me why?

Comment: Well - what did you want to do with this? Or is it out of curiosity?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points/

Comment: @Saphrosit Helping anyone you are not, by being a PITA.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 a[i++] = a[i++];
```

Because it is Undefined Behavior.

Good Read:
[Sequence Points](http://c-faq.com/expr/seqpoints.html)
[Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: Do you have a link at hand from the specs?

Comment: @Martin: See the links inline.They have every Standard specification you might need.